# Iranian seeking political asylum in Canada

Tags: canada, refugees, iran-citizens

I've been a political prisoner way back in my life, but I was living my life with many hardships that my background brought to me.  However, recently the political climate in my country has been so volatile so I am considering moving to Canada for political asylum.

My country is Iran and since you know there is no direct flight without a visa application or a Canadian Embassy in my country, I want to know how to approach my application and then fly. My son is a living in Canada so I can take tourist visa to Canada but how can I request a political asylum while I'm there.

Any legal advice or places that can help me how to go on by my business. an asylum when I go to Turkey to have my biometric data taken or should I come to Canada and then ask for asylum.

How my visa application for travel should be? It is recommended to provide a clean record

PS